# Select all table names from Oracle DB

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I write a program which scans all **tablenames** of a database and displays all

My Db has the Tables : User, Order,History

It should look like this:" Existing Tables: User Order History"

how should the command look like?

```
string SqlOrder="Select ??? from TestDB"
```

Comment: You need to fire the statement, get the results then format these in c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 'Existing Tables: ' || wm_concat(table_name) tablenames 
  FROM user_tables;
```

For the sample Oracle HR database it returns

```
TABLENAMES
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Existing Tables: REGIONS,LOCATIONS,DEPARTMENTS,JOBS,EMPLOYEES,JOB_HISTORY,COUNTRIES
```

**UPDATE:** Example with `LISTAGG()`

```
SELECT 'Existing Tables: ' || LISTAGG(table_name, ',') 
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY table_name) tablenames 
  FROM user_tables;
```

Comment: LISTAGG() could be relevant too : http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#listagg

Comment: Agree. Added to the answer.

Comment: This answere do exactly what i want to do thx !

Answer (score 1):

```
select table_name
from all_tables
```

More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2117.htm#i1592091

Comment: manual link is missing, besides i guess the OP didnt mean this

Comment: I understood it like he would like to have the string before the tablenames and the tablenames as coma separated which would explain tagging the question with the C# tag.

Comment: @TwoMore: but he still neeeds to select all table names somehow.

Comment: absolutly right, i have no problem with your answer but wonders if it answers the question, guess we will have to wait for the OP